# How to add more details inside the xml tags generated by cmarkup?

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

I am generating an sample.xml file using cmarkup parser as follows:

```
CMarkup xml;
xml.AddElem( "ORDER" );
xml.IntoElem();
xml.AddElem( "ITEM" );
xml.IntoElem();
xml.AddElem( "SN", "132487A-J" );
xml.AddElem( "NAME", "crank casing" );
xml.AddElem( "QTY", "1" );
```

Following is the generated sample.xml file:

```
<ORDER>
<ITEM>
<SN>132487A-J</SN>
<NAME>crank casing</NAME>
<QTY>1</QTY>
</ITEM>
</ORDER>
```

Now, i  want to add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

on the top of generated sample.xml and also want to add a line inside "ITEM" tag  as:

```
...
<ITEM>
<Person age="12" passed="Yes">Alive</Person>
....
</ITEM>
```

I searched for various methods in cmarkup to achieve this but i am not getting clearity there. So, please suggest me how can i add above mentioned two lines in xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
xml.SetDoc("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n");
....
xml.AddElem("Person", "Alive");
xml.SetAttrib("age", "12");
xml.SetAttrib("passed", "Yes");
```